# 2 php versions on same server

Tags: php, php5, installation

Is it possible to install 2 php versions on same server.

I have some old sites on my local system which supports php5.

But latest CMS and framework supports php5.3 . I don't want to change my old sites. But want all work perfectly.

So is it possible that I can install both versions or any other way to make workable all?

Comment: This is more of a serverfault question.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524508/how-can-one-run-multiple-versions-of-php-5-x-on-a-development-lamp-server

Comment: Sounds like a perfect opportunity/excuse to learn about Docker if you ask me ;)

Answer (score 0):

### First

You can use something like [fastCGI](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/5?q=node/10) or patch [php-fpm](http://php-fpm.org/) for versions up to 5.2.x

For versions PHP 5.3.x < 5.3.3 you can get [php-fpm](http://php-fpm.org/) from the php svn like this;

```
cd php-5.3.x (download and unzip php first)
svn co http://svn.php.net/repository/php/php-src/trunk/sapi/fpm sapi/fpm
./buildconf --force
./configure --enable-fpm ...your other configure options, etc...
make && make install
```

- After that you need to adjust the default config file (installed into $prefix/etc) and run "php-fpm".

(Instructions from http://php-fpm.org/download/)

For php 5.3.3 and later [php-fpm](http://php-fpm.org/) is included in the core. So  the only thing you need to do is compile php with `--enable-fpm`, se more [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.install.php).

### Second

Set up the different versions you need in different paths, and start them.

### Third

Then you can point your webserver to use different running php-processes depending on which php version you need.

Answer (score 0):

It heavily depends on your web server. Apache for example has the concept of ["handlers"](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/handler.html) which can be simply set to different values for your PHP files in the virtual directory configuration or within a .htaccess file like this:

```
 AddHandler php53-cgi .php
```

This way, you could set PHP versions per directory easily after you've defined the appropriate [Action directives](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_actions.html#action) for different PHP versions.